# PC shuts down when I put it into suspend/sleep mode and then it keeps restarting

Tags: bios, sleep, suspend, acpi

When I enable ACPI suspend S3 mode in BIOS my PC shuts down instead of suspending. When I turn it on it keeps restarting over and over again(I can't even get into BIOS), so I have to completely shut it down by cutting off electricity.

Comment: Did you (when it was running) set the suspend modes in your Operating System? Most operating systems have suspend setting for battery operation.

Comment: Try the following for BIOS.   First know what the Function Key to enter BIOS is (F1 is common). Shut down.  Now press the power button, and immediately press F1 repeatedly until you see the BIOS screen. Then reset BIOS to defaults. Save, exit and restart.

Comment: Is it mouse motion that wakes it?